# How to make a 3d surface/point plot with color based on a list

Tags: graphics3d, color, plotting

This is my data:

```
n = {0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 195, 
   210, 225, 240, 255, 270, 285, 300, 315, 330};

x = {5.74, 5.23, 5.94, 3.41, 1.69, 9.43, 0.16, 11.83, 4.83, 3.44, 
   9.29, 6.32, 9.02, 5.7, 5.09, 3.07, 0.6, 0.23, 0.13, 0.61, 4.99, 
   3.15, 8.26};

y = {4.8, 3.38, 3.38, 1.38, 0.23, 9.95, 0.92, 5.92, 4.42, 5.89, 8.06, 
   5.69, 4.46, 3.96, 4, 1.99, 0.2, 0.23, 0.46, 1.96, 12.16, 5.9, 6.12};

z = {0.7, 3.8, 7.12, 10.52, 6.59, 0.43, 10.04, 0.45, 5.56, 4.76, 3.4, 
   0.88, 0.77, 3.59, 5.78, 8.24, 7.94, 10.38, 10.19, 9.8, 6.42, 4.69, 
   3.01};
```

Where f(n)=(x,y,z). So I want to plot x,y,z where every color represents a different value from list n.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

I *think* something like this is what you're after:

```
ListPlot3D[Transpose[{x, y, z}], ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[x]]]
```

[image]

Put whatever tickles your fancy into the function for the mapping of `n` to colors, and check the documentation for `ColorFunction` (and associated things like `ColorFunctionScaling`) to fine-tune.

Comment: Normally we color Graphics 3D as a function (individual or combined ) of (x,y,z) right? That would perhaps be easier to define and display?

Comment: I tried this: ListPointPlot3D[{x, y, z}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]] But I am trying to make a 4D plot where color is the fourth dimension with every color representing a separate value from n. This statement gave me a lot of repeated colors

Answer (score 1):

You can make an interpolating function from your data, that takes `x, y, z` as inputs and returns a color based on the matching value of `n`,

```
colorfunc = 
 Interpolation[{{#1, #2, #3}, #4} & @@@ Transpose[{x, y, z, n}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]

ListPlot3D[Transpose[{x, y, z}], 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", MinMax@n}][
     colorfunc[#1, #2, #3]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", MinMax@n}], {0, 330}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]